# Use custom domain with IBM Bluemix website

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud

I want to reuse my existing domain (managed by IBM Hursley, but that shouldnt matter I think) with my new Bluemix website. What should I ask the team who manages my domain name and what I have to set in the Bluemix app/site?

Thanks,

Pimmy

Answer (score 7):

To integrate the answer from @umberto-manganiello you can also setup on your Registrar DNS configuration an **'A' Record** instead of a **'CNAME' record**, and making it to refer to the following IP addresses according to the Bluemix region where your application is running:

- US-SOUTH: 75.126.81.68
- EU-GB: 5.10.124.142
- AU-SYD: 168.1.35.169

This solution actually is working better that the CNAME one.

*Edit Aug 24th 2016:*

the IBM Bluemix platform added the following hostnames in order to allow customers to setup their custom domains (used with their IBM Bluemix applications) as CNAME of the following hostnames

- US South: secure.us-south.bluemix.net
- United Kingdom (EU-GB): secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net
- Sydney (AU-SYD): secure.au-syd.bluemix.net

The customers now can use the right hostname as CNAME value of their custom domain, according to the IBM Bluemix region their applications are running on

Comment: Where can I check out those IP addresses in case those will be change in the future?

Comment: These IP addesses won't change without a notification to Bluemix users, because are used by a great number of then. Anyway you would check on the Bluemix doc page suggested by Umberto and also the doc page related to the HTTPS certificate configuration

Comment: added the CNAME hostnames in the main answer, it allows to avoid using fixed IP addresses (helping in the case of IP addresses switch)

Answer (score 4):

To do this you have to perform two steps:

- First is the configuration on Bluemix:

From your Bluemix Dashboard, click your org's dropdown and choose Manage Organizations. Then click domains, and add domain. The domain is organization wide, which means you can link different subdomains to different applications. This can be useful if you have different components (e.g: blog, web application, web service). 
Once you’ve created the custom domain go back to your dashboard and select an application. Then on top you'll see a “Routes” label followed by a pencil icon (Edit routes and App Access). Click on the pencil button and add a route for www.yourdomain.com.

- Second is the DNS settings and URL forwarding you'll need on  your existing domain.

Now that Bluemix side is all set, ask your domain manager to forward yourdomain.com to www.yourdomain.com and  to add a CNAME record in DNS settings which points www.yourdomain.com to the appname.mybluemix.net that BlueMix provides by default.

If you need additional information please take a look at [Bluemix Docs - Creating and using a custom domain](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/updapps.html#domain)

Answer (score 3):

### Here is an example:

- My app name in Bluemix = askwatsonto
- My route in Bluemix = askwatsonto.mybluemix.net
- My domain name = askwatsonto.com
- My org =  carlos.ferreira@something.com

### Steps using the CF CLI:

- Download CF CLI: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/index.html#downloads
- Add your domain to your org: $cf create-domain carlos.ferreira@something.org askwatsonto.com
- Add route to your app: $cf map-route askwatsonto www.askwatsonto.com
- Add CNAME to your DNS provider.   I used domainmonster.com:
  [image]

  > My application was deployed in US-South. Use a different address for the following other regions:
  >
  > - US-SOUTH: secure.us-south.bluemix.net
  > - EU-GB: secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net
  > - AU-SYD: secure.au-syd.bluemix.net'

Debug DNS using this web site http://simpledns.com/lookup-dg.aspx

Read the doc: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/updapps.html#domain